# In Taurus, How to set "Clear cookies each iteration" to true?

Tags: jmeter, yaml, taurus

I am trying to clear cookies after each iteration in Taurus yaml.

I  tried the solution from below thread but it didn't work:
[Google Group]   https://groups.google.com/g/codename-taurus/c/wa4xIbxkUYI?pli=1

Above thread says:
For reference I did it like this:

```
    modifications:
      set-prop:
        "Cookies>CookieManager.clearEachIteration": "true"
```

I have tried the same but didn't work.

Using JMeter I can clear the cookies but need the same behavior for Taurus. Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "for Taurus"? Taurus just provides [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) configuration of **some of** JMeter test elements. The "solution" you're referring is for running existing .jmx script using Taurus

Taurus doesn't support 100% of JMeter functionality when it comes to [building test plan from config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config), refer the documentation to see what is supported.

If you want to use some JMeter functionality which is not supported by Taurus the options are in:

1. Reach out to Taurus developers via the forum you're referencing and ask them to implement the functionality you need
2. Implement it yourself, Taurus is an [open source project](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus)
3. Switch to the [existing .jmx script execution](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)
4. Switch to JMeter and stop using Taurus as a wrapper
5. Use [JR223 Test Elements](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks) to perform the removing of cookies, i.e. you could add a JSR223 PreProcessor to the first sampler in the Thread Group and call `sampler.getCookieManager().clear()` function there where [`sampler` stands for HTTPSamplerBase](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T. Added JSR223 Preprocessor.